# How to center antd Card in Col in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I want a card to in the center of the screen.
I have written the below code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Card, Col } from "antd";
const App = () => (
  <Col style={{height: '500px'}}>
    <Card style={{marginTop: '70%'}}>
      <p>Card content Card content Card content</p>
    </Card>
  </Col>
);
export default App;
```

I am fixing the height of Col but when I add marginTop for the Card it comes to that position but the height increases by the same amount. I don't want that to happen. I want the height to be fixed as mentioned in Col.
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

The API for aligning columns within rows looks terrible. If you apply a `span={24}` to the row it is still a `block`. Adding `flex` to it does not allow you to vertically center the Card within the Row.

I just stuck to plain CSS Flexbox to lay out the content.

- Row

  - `height: 500` ~ height of the row
  - `background: LightGrey` ~ show the Row bounds visually
  - `justify-content: center` ~ center the column horizintally
- Col

  - `display: flex` ~ Enable Flexbox (default for Col is `block`)
  - `background: yellow` ~ show the Col bounds visually
  - `align-items: center` ~ vertically center the Card
  - `justify-content: center` ~ horizontally center the Card
  - `flex: 1` ~ Stretch to fill the width of the Row
- Card

  - `background: magenta` ~ show the Card bounds visually

### App.jsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Card, Col, Row } from "antd";

const App = () => (
  <Row
    style={{
      height: 500,
      background: "LightGrey",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <Col
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        background: "yellow",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flex: 1
      }}
    >
      <Card style={{ background: "magenta" }} title="Card title">
        <p>Card content, Card content, Card content</p>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
export default App;
```

### styles.css

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Here's a link to a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-flexbox-override-nz49mh) that demonstrates the layout described above.

---

### Resources

For more on Flexbox layout visit:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/

These are helpful too:

- https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/interactive-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The explanation helped me a lot along with the references. Thank you. It actually helped me with other issues apart from the one asked here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can put something like: *top: 50%, left: 50%, translate-x: -50%, translate-y: -50%*. This will be centered in the middle of screen.

But if you need in the center of the Col, you can put the Col **display: flex, justify-content: center** and **align-items: center**.

Comment: Thank you. I have not used top much but got to know the importance of it. Now that I know about it, feel like I should have searched more. Will remember now.